# Why ogr doesn't read this kind of prj

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, epsg, prj

I run the code below, that I would hope to return the parameters from projection file (.prj). However it doesn't work as I would expected. I realized that the it isn't working because the some features of .prj file. I tried with another .prj file and the code has worked well. 
What is the problem to my code?

```
import ogr

# use Shapefile driver
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
# reference Shapefile
shp = "/home/dogosousa/Downloads/lc8_ba.shp"
# open the file
ds = driver.Open(shp, 0)
# reference the only layer in a Shapefile
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)

print(lyr.GetSpatialRef())

# projected coordinate system
proj_string = lyr.GetSpatialRef().GetAttrValue("PROJCS", 0)
# geographic coordinate system
geog_string = lyr.GetSpatialRef().GetAttrValue("GEOGCS", 0)
# EPSG Code if available
epsg = lyr.GetSpatialRef().GetAttrValue("AUTHORITY", 1)
# datum
datum = lyr.GetSpatialRef().GetAttrValue("DATUM", 0)

print(proj_string, geog_string, epsg,datum)
```

The .prj file that doesn't work with the code:

```
PROJCS["PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 24N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-39],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32624"]]",UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

The .prj file that works with the code:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WKT string in that .prj is corrupt. I don't know what wrote it, but the `PROJCS` and `UNITS` elements are repeated.

i.e. (indicated by --> <--)

```
-->PROJCS["<--PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 24N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-39],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32624"]]",-->UNIT["Meter",1]<--]
```

Removing the dupes works

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 24N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-39],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32624"]]"]
```

e.g.

```
from osgeo import osr

srs = osr.SpatialReference()

prj='PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 24N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-39],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32624"]]"'

srs.ImportFromWkt(prj)

# projected coordinate system
proj_string = srs.GetAttrValue("PROJCS", 0)
# geographic coordinate system
geog_string = srs.GetAttrValue("GEOGCS", 0)
# EPSG Code if available
epsg = srs.GetAttrValue("AUTHORITY", 1)
# datum
datum = srs.GetAttrValue("DATUM", 0)

print(proj_string, geog_string, epsg,datum)

WGS 84 / UTM zone 24N WGS 84 32624 WGS_1984
```

You can catch these sort of issues in future by enabling [gdal exceptions](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#PythonbindingsdonotraiseexceptionsunlessyouexplicitlycallUseExceptions), i.e. `gdal.UseExceptions()`, `ogr.UseExceptions()`, `osr.UseExceptions()`, e.g:

```
osr.UseExceptions()

prj='PROJCS["PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 24N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY[
"EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJE
CTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-39],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_eastin
g",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32624"]]"
,UNIT["Meter",1]]'

s.ImportFromWkt(prj)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
...
RuntimeError: OGR Error: Corrupt data
```

Comment: So. The lib that wrote the file is gdal-segment. The problem comes from it. I don't know why. I will report.

Comment: I don't know how, it just writes the exact SRS it reads from the source dataset https://github.com/cbalint13/gdal-segment/blob/master/src/io/vector.cpp#L177. Might be your input raster or a gdal bug.

Comment: My input data are a composition from landsat 8. I only compose the bands that I downloaded from USGS with gdal_merge.py https://github.com/dogosousa/preprocess2ta/blob/master/ComposeBands.py. I cliped them too in order to test more fast. I think it wouldn't a problem.

Comment: You can run gdalsrsinfo on any file in your workflow to see where GDAL refuses to read the CRS correctly. Might be a bug worth reporting if it is a GDAL component.

Comment: @AndreJ i will see it.